# How to redirect old url to new url django 1.9

Tags: regex, django, python-2.7

I am new in python django 1.9 and tried to redirect using urls.py file,

Here I explain actually what I tried.

**Old :** www.abc.com/c.aaa.html , www.abc.com/p.aaa.html and www.abc.com/books2

just redirect to home page like www.abc.com

```
url(r'/c.*$', include('apps.urls'),name='home'),
url(r'/p.*$', include('apps.urls'),name='home')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use django's base `RedirectView`. For example you could do this:

```
url(r'/c.aaa.html$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/'), name='go-to-home'),
```

Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses) documentation materials for information on how to do redirects in django.

Comment: I try to follow your answer but it return 404
and i have total 82 old url like c.aaa.html, c.bbbb.html ... etc

Comment: That was an example. Instead of `url='/'` try with the actual link which goes to the homepage. Also is there any pattern in your old urls? If this is the case, then you could write some regex to match all of them, something like this: `/[\w][.][\w+].html` and put them at the end of your `urlpatterns` list.

Comment: yes i got your point but actually django tried to find c.aaa.html and return The current URL, c.aaa.html, didn't match any of these.
in sort i thought regex not match..